# imbed shiny app into html-markdwon report

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

i would like to embed the following shiny app into an R markdown report (html):
https://agristat.shinyapps.io/Shiny_App_Schlachtvieh/

i have tried several ways to achieve this. for example:

```
url <- "https://agristat.shinyapps.io/Shiny_App_Schlachtvieh/"
knitr::include_app(url, height = "400px")
```

or

```
knitr::include_url("https://agristat.shinyapps.io/Shiny_App_Schlachtvieh/")
```

however with all these options i run into the same problem: the visualisation of the shiny-app will not appear in the knitted html-file. I have also opened the html-file with an internet explorer (see screenshot). I can select the inputs, but the visualisation will not be drawn.

what am i doing wrong? any suggestions? thanks a lot for any help and kind regards.

[scrrenshot of the imbeded shiny-app in a knitted html-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSigw.png)

Comment: One cannot embed R code in an HTML file and view it in an HTML browser expecting the browser to execute R code. `shiny` is R code, so if you want something interactive, it must be served by R somehow, one of: R console, RStudio IDE, shinyapps.io, RStudio Connect, or Shiny Server. There are some *components* available in shiny that are then made interactive via javascript alone (e.g., datatable with client-side tables; plotly, I believe), but R code itself is not going to work that way.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have stored the app on shinyapps.io (https://agristat.shinyapps.io/Shiny_App_Schlachtvieh/). Now, I just would like to embed it (via link) into an html-markdown-report. is this not possible?

Comment: @nicolas what browser did you use to open the generated HTML file? I just tried the `include_app()` method with a dummy R Markdown file, and it seems to be working fine with Edge and Firefox at least.

Comment: Okay, so you have a static HTML generated from rmarkdown. In that, you want either (a) an iframe, embedded an app served from shinyapps.io in your HTML report; or (b) an href link that opens a new browser/tab with your app. Is there a third option I'm not inferring?

Comment: @ Mikko, just tried it firefox: I get the same result I got with chrome (see screenshot): I can select the inputs of the App, but no visualisations...

Comment: @ r2evans, i guess (a) would be what want. (b) could also be a possible solution, if (a) is not achievable ...